# Benefits of storing uploads in an assets folder?

Tags: uploads, framework, responsive

I'm trying to get up to speed with responsive theme development in Wordpress and have been looking at Bootstrap and combining it with HTML5 boilerplate. I came across this skeleton framework which combines both of them:

http://www.rootstheme.com/

However, it sets up the uploads folder to be /assets/ in the root of my site. Is there any benefit to doing that? This theme looks like it's doing a load of good stuff, so I'm assuming there's a benefit to do so?

Thanks

Osu

Comment: Its not setting the uploads folder to be /assets/ , its only rewriting the urls.

Comment: Hi @Bainternet - I realise it's rewriting the URLs for the theme assets like the CSS files etc., but this theme also sets the uploads folder to 'assets' in the admin end and creates a folder in the root of my site from what I can see.

Answer (score 1):

The only directory a theme or a plugin should write to is the `uploads` directory. That is the only directory with guaranteed write access (besides the server’s temporary directory).

Anything else is wrong and might not work.

There is no practical difference between both, except one: the upload directory may be on another (sub) domain to save HTTP data. Cookies aren’t sent to other domains, so an upload directory *inside* of the WordPress domain might be slower.